# Custom icon is not centered

Tags: java, google-maps

I am trying to add a marker on my site. Everything is working but I saw that marker always is slightly shifted in relation to this where I clicked. Additionally this problem occur only when I try to add a custom icon. All is correct when I use the default icon marker.

Part of code responsible for adding marker on my site:

```
 lastMarker = new google.maps.Marker( 
        position : location,
        map: mapDefault,
        draggable : true,
        icon : { 
                path : fontawesome.markers.MAP_MARKER,
                scale : 0.75,
                strokeWeight : 0.2,
                strokeColor : 'black',
                strokeOpacity : 1,
                fillColor : $('#quest_marker'+ 
                              currentPageButton).attr('data-
                              value'),
                fillOpacity : 1,}
});
```

As a result of this I received something like this:

[image: Image demonstrating the marking is shifted a few pixels to the rigth of the clicked area]

When I try to add default icon then is correct:

[image: Image demonstrating the marker is on the correct spot where the user clicked]

What causes this problem, and how to solve it.

Comment: if your png size 32,32, then you adjust icon's anchor: new google.maps.Point(16,32). so, you can point tip of your icon.

Comment: It works ! :D Very very thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use icon's `anchor` option

For example;
If your png size 32,32, then you adjust icon's anchor like this:

```
icon:{
  ...
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(16,32)
}
```

So, you can point tip of your icon.